# How to create a field mapping in Azure Search with a complex targetField

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I use the Azure Search indexer to index documents from a MongoDB CosmosDB which contains objects with fields named `_id`. 
As Azure Search does not allow underscores at the beginning of a field name in the index, I want to create a field mapping.

JSON structure in Cosmos --> structure in index

```
{
  "id": "test"
  "name": "test",
  "productLine": {
     "_id": "123",       --> "id": "123"
     "name": "test"
  }
}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#set-up-field-mappings) has exactly this scenario as an example **but** only for a top level field.

`"fieldMappings" : [ { "sourceFieldName" : "_id", "targetFieldName" : "id" } ]}`

I tried the following:

`"fieldMappings" : [ { "sourceFieldName" : "productLine/_id", "targetFieldName" : "productLine/id" } ] }`

that results in an error stating:

`Value is not accepted. Valid values: "doc_id", "name", "productName".`

**What is the correct way to create a mapping for a target field that is a subfield?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to directly map subfields. You can get around this by adding a [Skillset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/skillset-operations) with a [Shaper cognitive skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-shaper#scenario-1-complex-types) to the [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer#request-syntax), and an [output field mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-output-field-mapping#use-outputfieldmappings).

You will also want to [attach a Cognitive Services resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-attach-cognitive-services) to the skillset. The [shaper skill doesn't get billed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-attach-cognitive-services#use-billable-resources), but attaching a Cognitive Services resource allows you to [process more than 20 documents per day](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-attach-cognitive-services#use-free-resources).

**Shaper skill**

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ShaperSkill",
  "context": "/document",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "source": "/document/productLine/_id"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "source": "/document/productLine/name"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "output",
      "targetName": "renamedProductLine"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Indexer skillset and output field mapping**

```
"skillsetName": <skillsetName>,
"outputFieldMappings": [
    {
        "sourceFieldName": "/document/renamedProductLine",
        "targetFieldName": "productLine"
    }
]
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! Just FYI (because it wasn't immediately clear to me), after creating the skill and skillset, you need to add the skillset to the indexer.